# Accessing resources during initialization of control

Tags: wpf, silverlight

lets assume we have the following control definition

```
<ctrl:ChildWindow x:Class="Control.Editor"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls" 
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Control"
                  Width="400" Height="300"
                  local:AttachedProperties.DialogResult="{Binding Path=DialogResult}"
                  Title="{Binding Path=Caption}" Style="{StaticResource Title}" DataContext="{Binding}" HasCloseButton="False">
    <ctrl:ChildWindow.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Control;component/Resources/BaseAppearance.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ctrl:ChildWindow.Resources>
</ctrl:ChildWindow>
```

The problem is that the style on the root control cannot be set because the `ResourceDictionary` is not loaded.

How can I get access to the `StaticResource Title` during the initialization of the control, when I don't have access to the `App` class? I'm also not sure that it would be possible, if I would have access to it.

Regards

Comment: WPF or Silverlight?  Solutions will differ.

Comment: Actually for Silverlight but I hope that there is a common solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend accessing your resource and doing the work in the .Loaded() event of your control.

Edit: On second thought... I think I know what you're doing now... You have a resource set in your App.xaml class, but you want to access it in your control.

Easy way around the problem is to set it to a DynamicResource instead... but this is less performant.

What is the BuildAction set to on your App.xaml in the property's tab?
If it is ApplicationDefinition... then you should be able to access your resource as you currently are.

Comment: As I mentioned before I don't have access to the App class. So I cannot load the resource there. It would be easy, when I would have this option. DynamicResource is not the best solution because it won't work in Silverlight. Or am I wrong in this point?

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant by you don't have access to the App class. And I believe you're correc about Silverlight... in which case... I think code behind in the .Loaded() event is probably your best bet. (Unless there is some ApplicationDefinition class that you have access to you that shares resources with your custom control... in which case you can load your resource dictionary there).

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that the Loaded event will work because InitializeComponents() (the crash site) is executed in the constructor, which is definitely executed before the Loaded event is raised.

Comment: You'll have to first remove Style="{StaticResource Title}" from <ctrl:ChildWindow> as I think that's what's causing the crash. Then you can manually set the ChildWindow's Style to your Title resource in the Loaded event. (If that's not what's causing the crash, could you provide more code?)

Comment: Ah ok. You're right. I should have spend a few seconds more on thinking about your solution. My hope was that a solution could be found without code behind. Lesson learned, avoiding code behind what ever it takes makes me unflexible. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I found the common way without using code behind. I knew it is possible. ^^

```
<ctrl:ChildWindow x:Class="Control.Editor"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls" 
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Control"
                  Width="400" Height="300"
                  local:AttachedProperties.DialogResult="{Binding Path=DialogResult}"
                  Title="{Binding Path=Caption}" DataContext="{Binding}" HasCloseButton="False">
    <ctrl:ChildWindow.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Control;component/Resources/BaseAppearance.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ctrl:ChildWindow.Resources>
    <crtl:ChildWindow.Style>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="Title" />
    </crtl:ChildWindow.Style>
</ctrl:ChildWindow>
```